# How to interpret the negation in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I have a question. What does the following sentence mean? Negation is so complicated here.

> We are characters who do not exist in a story composed by no one from nothing.

Comment: That sentence does not really make a whole lot of sense. It sounds like it’s meant to be explained in the following text. The negations are not really complicated: it’s just that the things being described are quite … odd. In a nonexistent kind of way. “A story composed by no one from nothing” could be taken as an atheist description of the Universe (composed by no one = no God to ‘write’ the story; from nothing = from the nothingness ‘surrounding’ the Big Bang), but why we (humans?) would then be characters who do not exist there is beyond me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because in the absence of any context, it is unclear what is being asked.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Au contraire, [negation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) is ***very*** complicated, in the way it's used. Logically, nothing could be simpler -- Negation is the only significant monadic truth functor; but logic is not language, and negation is not truth-functional in natural language. [Logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) is to language as mathematics is to physics -- i.e, it's just a skeleton representation, not the real thing, and most of it's unknown, but you can't see how the details work without it.

Comment: But these characters don't exist in that story, where there's not an author. Right? So I thought it meant that we are in a story ruled by someone. What do you think?

Comment: @JohnLawler, I agree that negation as a concept is a complex thing. I just meant that the negations in this sentence are no more complicated than any other negation—it is not the negations or the way they are used that make the sentence so abstruse, but the fact that the sentence itself is just not very clear.

Comment: And the fact that every single thing that could be negated was negated, allowing no room for any context.

Comment: You can read more about that phrase here: http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/books/2013/08/this-week-in-fiction-robert-coover-the-colonels-daughter.html

Comment: @user814064 If that is the original text and the author's response, then our answer is right there. -- At the end of the story, someone says, “But we are characters who do not exist in a story composed by no one from nothing.” A moment of self-deprecation or metafiction?  'No, this is merely life’s (and literature’s, for those caught up in it) sad truth. In the end, I’m a realist.' -- So it seems the author's intent was in fact a nihilistic statement, though one could also take it (as the critic did) as self-depreciating or a meta-fictional comment.

Answer (score 2):

It is a very clumsy sentence since it can be read in multiple ways. @Zibbobz and @mplungjan gave one interpretation, Another could be

> We are *not* characters from a story [...]

meaning that we are not characters from a story at all. Or

> We are *not* characters from a story composed by *no one* [...]

meaning, that we are characters from a story but this story has been composed by someone.

If it were correctly punctuated, the meaning would be clearer:

> We are characters who do not exist, in a story composed by no one from nothing.

With the added comma the meaning given by the other answers is clear. In its absence, the sentence can be read to mean either that *we are characters in...* or equally that *we are not characters in...*

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down.

> We are characters who do not exist...

(We have no existence)

> ...in a story composed by no one...

(We have no creator)

> ...from nothing.

(We are made from no original substance)

I can't determine exactly what the author meant without more context, but I would guess he's making a point about the nature of reality.  He, or the character saying it, is saying that we (the group or we human beings in general) do not exist, that our story has no author, and that we were created out of nothingness.

It's a very nihilistic viewpoint, basically saying we are nothing, we have no creator, and we were made out of nothingness.

It could just as easily be a statement defying predestination and declaring that we shape who we are on our own, but the real meaning of the phrase is likely connected to whomever is saying it, and the reason they have for saying it.

Answer (score 1):

Subject to interpretation by context, I would say that the sentence is a simple assertion of nihilism. Its (apparently) purposely paradoxical nature (simple negation of everything that could be negated) is just there to emphasize the utter purposelessness of life as perceived by the speaker.

Comment: Agreed. I should have read this more carefully before my post, but I elaborated it a bit at least.

Comment: Not, never, nohow. Actually, it sounds a bit like a poor parody of _Life's but a walking shadow, a poor player
That struts and frets his hour upon the stage
And then is heard no more. It is a tale
Told by an idiot, full of sound and fury
Signifying nothing._ A very poor parody.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the author was using some poetic license in creating the sentence, and I suspect that it was not intended to be read literally, but simply to point to a greater nihilism most likely explored in the sentence's context. In short, analyzing the exact negations involved may cause you to lose the full meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Very straight forward. No complicated negations

> We are characters that do not exist

Non existent characters

> In a story composed by no one

That story was not written by anybody - so perhaps it just materialised

> from nothing

and it was written from nothing

Answer (score 0):

I think what this fancy sentence implies is clearly that:

**We are characters [who do not exist] in a story by no one from nothing**

or

**We are not characters in a story by no one from nothing**

even

**We are characters in a story by someone from something**

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could go about interpreting the sentence.

1. That you actually attempt to interpret a meaning from its literal structure.
2. Understand the intention of the person when issuing this sentence.

Let's look at the following scenario. A girl is tired of helping her dad dodge phone calls from an overly-persistent relative (perhaps, overly-attached girlfriend). Finally, when the next call came, the girl responded to the caller,

> My dad says he's not here.

Do you wish to even attempt to squeeze a meaning out of the literal sentence, or would you simply settle with the fact that the girl is politely saying, "Stop your freakin phone calls. My dad doesn't want to speak to you."??

After the story line of the movie changed for the umpteenth time, in an attempt to mould plausible events into an implausible movie, a leading member of the cast remarked at their production crew, when again told of changes ...

> We are characters who do not exist in a story composed by no one from nothing.

Should the producer attempt to interpret a meaning from the literal structure of the sentence? Or should the producer simply smile at the [penrose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_triangle) sarcasm expressed depicting the viability of the production from going forward? (Another [penrose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_stairs) sarcasm).

The conservative management of an in-town delivery company had become rather militant at instituting daily drug screening on his drivers and in ensuring they were not cavorting with persons of questionable trades on company premises. Regardless that none of his drivers were indulging in any of those activities, he had simply decided he had to make a point to his employees. Piqued by the inconsiderate intentions of his boss, the foreman finally declared when pressed on carrying out the checks steadfastly,

> There ain't no driver smoking no joint with no whore on your premises. It's a thousand percent guarantee from me.

Is it even possible for 1000% guarantee to exist within the context of the conversation? Is it worthwhile to interpret the literal phrases, or is there a higher calling for those sentences?